# negative outward normal derivative implies positiveness near the boundary.

Tags: calculus, regularity-theory-of-pdes

So, this seens to be simple but I could not handle to prove it:

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded and open domain of $\mathbb R^N$ with smooth boundary (as smooth as you want), $N\geq 2$ and that $u\in C^1(\overline\Omega,\mathbb R)$ is a function such that $\partial u/\partial\nu<0$ all over $\partial\Omega$, where $\nu$ denotes the outward normal unit vector on $\partial \Omega$.

Is it true that $u>0$ near the boundary? That means: can a $\delta>0$ be chosen such that $u(x)>0$ for all $x\in\{y\in\Omega;\ dist(y,\partial\Omega)<\delta\}$?

Comment: Yes, it is true (if $\partial\Omega$ is at least $C^1$), but thinking about its proof: do you know "some" differential topology? (I mean, tubular neighborhood?).

Comment: You will find some help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839762/positivity-of-a-normal-derivative-of-c2-function?noredirect=1#comment5856166_2839762

Comment: Yes, differential Topology is not a monster I haven't seen! But anyways, I forgot to mention that $u\equiv 0$ on the boundary but I think you figured out that.

Comment: Gustave, thanks for the link, but it seems that my question is exactly the opposite: I need positiveness of $u$ near the boundary knowing the condition over its normal derivative. And this is of course true near each point of the boundary but I need a kind of uniformity on this behaviour, as stated in the question.

Comment: @bhcribeiro In all that talk about tubular neighborhood the essential thing is that the mapping $\partial\Omega\times(-\delta,\delta)\ni (x,s)\mapsto x+s\nu(x)\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is, for $\delta>0$ sufficiently small, a $C^1$ diffeomorphism of $\partial\Omega\times(-\delta,\delta)$ onto its image (this follows by the inverse function theorem). In particular, **every** $y\in\Omega$ sufficiently close to $\partial\Omega$ can be *uniquely* written as $x+s\nu(x)$ for some $x\in\partial\Omega$ and $s\in(-\delta,0]$. If you have this, the remaining part is simple calculus.

Comment: For example, on pp. 139-140 of Lee's [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387217529) there is a proof of the theorem I was talking about in my previous comment (don't be scared by the terminology; just look at Figs. 6.7 and 6.8).