# The interior of the set of continuously differentiable nonnegative functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set with smooth boundary. Consider the space $$C^1_0(\overline{\Omega}) := \{u \in C^{1}(\overline{\Omega}) : u = 0\text{ in }\partial \Omega\}$$
with the norm
$$
\|u\| = \|u\|_{\infty} + \|\,|\nabla u|\,\|_{\infty}
,\quad \forall u \in C^1_0(\overline{\Omega}).$$
Also consider $P = \{u \in C^1_0(\overline{\Omega}) : u \geq 0\}$. How can I show that $int(P) = A$, where
$$
A = \{ u \in C^1_0(\overline{\Omega}) : u(x) > 0, \forall x \in \Omega \text{ and }\langle \nabla u(x), \eta(x)\rangle < 0, \forall x \in \partial \Omega\} ?
$$

Given a point $u \in A$, I know that it's graphic has a specific behavior in the boundary, because the cosine of the angle between the gradient and the normal vectors in the boundary is negative. I imagine that a ball around it should be a "curved cover" involving its graphic. However, I didn't succeed in showing that there's a very small $r > 0$ such that the functions on the open ball $B_{r}(u)$ should be nonnegative.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this question from a book?

Comment: It is an exercise my teacher gave. I dont really know if he took it from a book.

Comment: In what context are you studying these spaces, would it be in a course of PDE's?

Comment: Yes, I'm studying non variational methods. My professor proved the existence of a principal eigenvalue for a second order elliptical operator using Krein-Rutman theorem, which needs, as a hypothesis, that the set $P$ has non empty interior.

Comment: That's cool, I really liked this problem. If you manage to solve it, could you post the answer here? It might help other people.

Comment: I found this reference: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~grsam/HS16/NumPDE/Extras/krein_rutman.pdf. Maybe it is sufficient to prove that $A \subset \operatorname{int}(P)$.

Comment: Thank you, Victor.

Comment: Just to complete, this is the first chapter of the book Yihong Du - Order Structure and Topological Methods in Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations - Maximum Principles and Applications.

Comment: This question was really well elaborated. Who is your teacher?

Comment: I'm also from Brazil. :)

Comment: Very nice my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea of how I think the proof can be done.

Let $u \in A$ and denote by $\partial_\eta$ the outer normal derivative. Since $\partial \Omega$ is compact, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\sup_{x \in \partial \Omega}\partial_\eta u(x) < - \delta <0$. Now, since $u \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $\partial \Omega$ on which $\partial_\eta u \leq - \delta/2$ (use the continuity of $\partial_\eta u$ in $x \in \partial \Omega$ with $\varepsilon=\delta/2$ combined with the compactness of $\partial \Omega$). Let
$$\alpha=\inf\{u(x):x \in \Omega \setminus N\}$$ and
$$\beta=\min\{\alpha, \delta/2\}.$$

We claim that $B(u,\beta) \subset P$.

Indeed, let $v \in C_0^1(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $\|u-v\|<\beta$. Then,
$$|u(x)-v(x)|<\alpha, \hbox{ for all } x \in \Omega.$$

In particular, if $x \in \Omega\setminus N$, we obtain that
$$-\alpha<u(x)-v(x)<\alpha,$$
which implies that
$$0\leq u(x)-\alpha<v(x),$$
since $u(x) \geq \alpha$ in $\Omega \setminus N$.

If $x \in N$, we obtain that
$$\left|\partial_\eta u(x)-\partial_\eta v(x) \right|=|\langle \nabla (u-v)(x), \eta \rangle | \leq |\nabla(u-v)(x)| <\delta/2, \hbox{ for all }  x \in N.$$

Therefore,
$$\partial_\eta v(x) < \partial_\eta u(x)+\delta/2<-\delta+\delta/2,\hbox{ for all } x \in N.$$

By using this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867353/negative-outward-normal-derivative-implies-positiveness-near-the-boundary): we obtain that
$$v(x) >0 \hbox{ for all } x \in N.$$
Consequently, $v(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}$, which implies that $B(u,\beta) \subset P$ and hence, $u \in \operatorname{int}(P)$.

Comment: Very nice solution Victor! I really thank you a lot.